# Shape of a static capillary surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, water, fluid-statics, surface-tension, capillary-action

I am studying the effects of surface tension and in particular the shape of a capillary interface in hydrostatic condition.
Let's recall the Young-Laplace Equation

$ \Delta P = \sigma \bigg(\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}\bigg)$

where $\sigma$ is the surface tension at a given temperature, $\Delta P$ the pressure gap between the two sides of the interface and $R_1$ and $R_2$ the curvature radii. Let's consider:

- a vertical coordinate $z$ positive in the direction of the gravity acceleration $g_0$;
- inside the interface water and out side air (a pendant drop or a liquid bridge, for example).

If the Bond number $Bo >> 1 $, then I have to take into account gravity effects, that is the $\Delta P$ is a funcion of $z$. If I set a reference pressure at $z_0 = 0$, then $p(z) = p_0 + \rho g_0 z$ (Stevin law). Then I don't understand why $\Delta P = p(z) - p_0$ (look at [Shape of static interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_surface#Static_interfaces)). Isn't $p_0$ the pressure *inside* the interface at $ z_0$? I have assumed that with the Stevin law I am able to find the pressure at every $z$ *inside* the liquid, thus getting the the $\Delta P = p(z) - p_{\text{air}}$, assuming $p_{\text{air}} = cost$ everywhere.

Thanks to those who will help!